# Writing struct containing dynamic array to binary file (C)

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles, fwrite, dynamic-arrays

I'm writing a program that writes arrays and the information regarding them to a binary file.

My first approach was to call fwrite 4 times: once for general information regarding the array, once for the timestamp, once for the dimension of the array and once to write the array itself.
This approach worked as it is quite simple, but the execution times were too slow, seeing as the program is multithreaded and it writes to a SAS drive frequently, flooding the drive with requests which presented a bottleneck.

The new approach was to create an array of structs containing the information needed, my struct would be as follows:

```
struct array_data{
    int information;
    int timestamp;
    int size;
    int* data_array;
}
```

During execution I would write the data to a buffer and when I had everything I need it would call a malloc to allocate `array_data.data_array` and copy everything from the buffer from inside a for loop.

The issue is when I call fwrite to write the whole struct, the first 3 members of the struct are written correctly, while the array is not and that is due to the address of the array not being contiguous, since it points to another place in memory after the malloc.

The best solution to this would be to declare the data_array as a static array, this way the fwrite would work as I need it to, but then I would have to call fwrite for every struct, instead of calling it once to write an array of structs, which would impact the performance, negating the use of the struct.

I've also tried using an array of dynamically allocated structs, by declaring my struct as follows:

```
struct array_data{
    int information;
    int timestamp;
    int size;
    int data_array[];
}
```

and allocating the array of structs using malloc, but the address of `struct_array[1].information` is not the one right after the `struct_array[0].data_array[last_index]`, there seems to be another 5 bytes in between, so if I were to call fwrite with struct_array the data in the file would still be incorrect.

Is there a way to use structs to solve this issue or should I just stick with writing my arrays to the file as I did in the first place?

Comment: You _can_ write the whole structo file, even with the address of `data`. Upon reading back you must ignore this address. After writing the struct you write `size` integers contained in data. When reading back the struct you allocate `size` integers in the `data` pointer and then read those from the file into the allocated array.

Comment: As for your question "_Is there a way to use structs to solve this issue_": no there is no way (because the data is a dynamic size allocated at run-time).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie when you say `data` I guess you refer to the array of structs, I can indeed write the struct, but the dynamically allocated array inside struct is not present in the file, since its location in memory is different than what I'd expect, as an example `&information=0`, `&timestamp=4`, `&size=8`, `&data_array=12`, but `&data_array[0]=300`, so the array is not physically present in the struct, but rather its pointer is, so calling fwrite to write the array of structs would not write the correct `data_array` elements

Comment: You could reduce your number of `fwrite` calls from 4 to 2. One call to write the header and one call to write the data. You can even use your `struct array_data` to hold the header, and use `offsetof(struct array_data, data)` for the number of header bytes. (The `offsetof` macro is defined by `#include <stddef.h>`.) However, on 64-bit systems there is likely to be padding in the structure before the `int* data_array` member.

Comment: Your first approach should be OK providing you use [`setvbuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setvbuf/) with a large buffer size.

Comment: Generally if I need to make few larger writes than many smaller writes I will accumulate the data in a buffer in memory exactly the same way it would exist in the file, and when that buffer is full I will write it to the file. The format of the data would likely be what you've done. Add the static part of the struct, the size of the dynamic data, and the dynamic data right after it.

Comment: *"the address of the array not being contiguous"*, this is a bit misleading statement. The value of `data_array` *is* stored contiguously inside the struct, but the value itself is a pointer to a certain place in memory. If this area doesn't change, your serializer function could simply write the first three values, and then the actual array. But even this is not portable: struct layout in memory and integer endianness are compiler- and architecture-dependent. The best approach would be to have a plain buffer and write the values using a specific format (protocol), before flushing it.

Comment: In order to answer this, we will need to see the code doing the file access and the code doing the allocation.

Comment: Tl;dr if you are doing something like `memcpy(dst, (char*)my_struct, sizeof(my_struct))`, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Jabberwocky thank you for pointing out that function. I've created a buffer using it and now it seems to run much better!

Answer (score 0):

The following example creates, writes and reads your data. It is just a outline. Error checks on `malloc`, `fread` and `fwrite` ommitted:

```
#define N_DATA 10
#define N_INTS 5

struct array_data{
    int information;
    int timestamp;
    int size;
    int* data_array;
};
struct array_data arr[N_DATA];

void makeData(void){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<N_DATA;i++) {
        arr[i].data_array=malloc(N_INTS*sizeof(int));
        arr[i].size= N_INTS;
    }
}
void writeData(FILE *fp_out)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<N_DATA;i++) {
        fwrite(&arr[i],sizeof(arr[i]),1,fp_out);
        fwrite(arr[i].data_array,arr[i].size*sizeof(int),1,fp_out);
    }
}
void readData(FILE *fp_in)
{
    int i= 0;
    while(fread(&arr[i],sizeof(arr[i]),1,fp_in)==1) {
        arr[i].data_array=malloc(arr[i].size*sizeof(int));
        fread(arr[i].data_array,arr[i].size*sizeof(int),1,fp_in);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your example, this is what I was considering doing, but using my first approach with a larger buffer for writing as was suggested I was able to improve the execution times